# Recommended i18n file contents structuring

Tags: angular, internationalization, ngx-translate

I'm working on a large, enterprise level system with many components, modules, and therefore translatable strings.

Is there a recommended way to organize the contents of my language files?

Since the application has grown, I'm searching for an optimized way to structure my translations.